# Increment history stops history search in Ruby 2.7.0 IRB

Tags: ruby, irb, ruby-2.7

If I have the following lines in my `~/.inputrc` then I can no longer use the up and down arrows to navigate the history in IRB:

```
# Incremental searching with Up and Down. Type 'ssh <up>' to get the last 'ssh' command you used
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

Is there anyway to get this working? This worked previously with Ruby 2.6.x so I presume it's something to do with the reline implementation in 2.7

Comment: I've found this workaround:

```
$if Ruby

$else
  "\e[A": history-search-backward
  "\e[B": history-search-forward
$endif
```

Comment: Use single backticks in comments, not triple.

Comment: I've found this workaround:
`
$if Ruby
$else
  "\e[A": history-search-backward "\e[B": history-search-forward
$endif
`

Comment: I'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 5):

I've found this workaround:

```
$if Ruby
$else
  "\e[A": history-search-backward
  "\e[B": history-search-forward
$endif
```

Answer (score -2):

I fixed this based on the comment from @anothermh

Use single quotes instead of double quotes. So like this:

```
'\e[A': history-search-backward
'\e[B': history-search-forward
```

Comment: This also changes the behavior of the up and down arrow keys in the console (they stop performing a history search)